# How to make one thread wait for a part of another thread to finish?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

Inside a function called Record, I create a thread. Let the thread function be called ThreadFn.
I want Record to wait till a block of code in ThreadFn starting from the beginning of ThreadFn completes.
How do I do this? I have been trying with Mutex. But I am not sure where to put CreateMutex and where to put ReleaseMutex.

I tried the following. But it is not working.
Have a global variable

```
HANDLE ghMutex = NULL;
```

Inside ThreadFn:
At the beginning

```
ghMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
```

When the block of code has finished, then

```
ReleaseMutex(ghMutex);
```

Inside Record:

```
Create the thread
WaitForSingleObject(ghMutex, INFINITE);
Close thread handle
CloseHandle(ghMutex);
```

Comment: Not working. The caller is not waiting.

Comment: Why do devs continually try to misuse mutex?   If you want to signal the other thread, use an appropriate synchro object.  Look up 'Event' and/or 'Semaphore'.  Either will do what you seem to want.  A mutex is just the wrong object to use for this.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit why do you have to be condescending? He's clearly here posting this question for a reason. Either he is limited to using just a mutex or he didn't know about  'Event' and/or 'Semaphore'.

Comment: @GaryJohnson are you aware of any OS that provides a mutex, but not events or semaphores?  I don't see my comment as condescending - I genuinely want to know why so many SO question posters try to use inappropriate sybchronization primitives.  Are they being taught badly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a cv for this. [Condition Variable](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/condition_variable/condition_variable/)

```
mutex m;
bool ready = false;
condition_variable cv;

Record() {
    //some code

    //create thread
    createThread(Threadfn());


    //get the lock
    m.lock();
    //waits until it gets a signal call     
    while (!ready) cv.wait(m);

   //continues code
}

Threadfn() {

    //get the lock
    m.lock();

    // run code

    // tell Record that it can continue again
    ready = true;
    m.unlock();
    cv.notify_one();

}
```

What happens is `Record()` locks a mutex and hangs on `while (!ready) cv.wait(lck)` until it is signaled by `Threadfn()`.

Comment: Note that OP is using Windows, and not all Windows versions support condition variables, (though I suspect that most, if not all, currently supported ones do:).

Comment: Gary, I am not aware of condition_variable. I will read about it. However, in the mean time, I read more about Mutex and Events and now I have been able to solve the problem that I posted. Thanks.

Comment: @Avinash Good to hear that you have it solved. Word of advice though, be very cautious when it comes to multi-threaded programming. Race conditions can be happening that may not expose the bug - until it does.

Comment: Yes, I had to take care of race conditions. Another problem I faced is that memory getting freed before a thread can access it. Suppose in function f1, I create a local variable and pass it as parameter to a thread function.The function f1 returns but the thread function is still using that variable. But the variable has already been destroyed because it was allocated on stack. Anyway, I took care of that by allocating the variable on heap.